# meu textarea não quer mostrar o conteúdo contigo no meu ngmodel

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um objeto que recebo de uma requisição, estou tentando colocar o valor deste atributo no template mas não aparece no textarea.

```
for(let i=0;i<this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.length;i++){
  if(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[i].descricao_b2w == null){
    console.log('entrou no nulo')
    this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[i].descricao_b2w = {descricao: null, id: null};
  }
}
```

Nessa função eu verifico se o descricao_b2w é nulo, se for eu crio chaves e valores com valor nulo (fiz isso porque estava dando erro no template quando o descricao_b2w objeto era nulo, então não conseguia encontrar a chave descricao, alegava que era undefined).

Meu template:

```
<div *ngFor="let produto of produtosConfirmadosAnuncio; let i = index" class="col-xl-4">

    <textarea class="form-control" 
    name="message"
    rows="3"
    [(ngModel)]="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao"
    #message='ngModel'
    >{{produto.descricao_b2w.descricao}}</textarea>
```

Também tentei:

```
   <textarea class="form-control" 
    name="message"
    rows="3"
    [(ngModel)]="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao"
    #message='ngModel'
    >{{produto.descricao_b2w.descricao}}</textarea>
```

e tambem tentei:

```
<textarea class="form-control" 
rows="3"
[(ngModel)]="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao"
></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra mim funcionou dessa forma:

```
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" #textbox (change)="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao = textbox.value">{{ produto.descricao_b2w.descricao }}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma

```
[ngModel]="produto?.descricao_b2w?.descricao" (ngModelChange)="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao = $event"
```

Comment: Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at

Comment: acho que precisa colocar no anterior também, da uma olhada agora

Comment: deu o mesmo erro, mas consegui aqui, obrigado

Comment: mudei novamente